# VBA macros use variable and cell reference in yearfrac function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate the years between dates using a variable and a cell reference but so far everything I have tried returns an invalid argument (or equivalent) error. Basic premise is cells("G2").Formula = "=YEARFRAC(F2, dt)". The variable dt is equal to the last day of the previous month (I know this works because I have tested using MsgBox, so assume the issue is the syntax). The cell F2 contains a date in the form 13-Jan-2018. Can someone please advise of the correct syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inserting this formula into the cell as a string using VBA. The string "dt" will therefore be inserted verbatim (not the variable).

If you want to insert the date value of dt as stored in VBA at the time, you'll have to use:

```
Dim dtstr as string
dtstr = Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Range("G2").Formula = "=YEARFRAC(F2, DATEVALUE(""" & dtstr & """))"
```

Note that I have converted dt to a string value for insertion into the cell formula in a standard format.

Comment: Well-spotted, YowE3K. Edited.